# 2010s movie where a girl gets this gem thingy that can stop/turn back time

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a movie I watched a few years back. 2012-2015 I’m sure. This girl gets this object that allows her to turn back time/look into the future I guess.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There aren't very many details here; you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good questions to see if they can help you recall any details.  If this is an anime there are [anime-specific suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) as well.

Comment: possibly looking for this the same film as this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186216/manga-where-a-girl-travels-back-in-time-after-the-guy-who-liked-her-died?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Very scant info in your question but it is possible that this is one of the versions of *The Girl Who Leapt Through Time*. There is an anime version from 2006 in which the object that allows time travel was a small nut-shaped item which you can clearly see in the trailer at about 34 seconds...

.. and also a live action version from 2011 which is much closer to your time frame. I have not seen this one and so cannot comment on the item that initiates the time travel. The trailers are on YouTube.